# WKWebview not working correctly on preload

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I'm trying to count pages on multiple `HTML`s using `WKWebview`'s `loadHtmlString` and than -

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.offsetHeight") { (webViewHeight, err) in 
                    numberOfPages = Int(ceil(CGFloat(webViewHeight) / webView.frame.height))
                }
}
```

But when I try to call my first `loadHtmlString`, on this webview, (only at the first HTML call... When I call `loadHtmlString` again on the same webview it works fine) I get false `height` on this first attempt (because the text of the HTML is not rendered or ignoring the css or something - I get 25 instead of 90)

I need to get the right height on the first try, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the WKWebview from URL like that:

```
let url : URL = URL(string: strUrl)!
 webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
```

And From HTML String like that:

```
webView.loadHTMLString(htmlStr, baseURL: nil)
```